# Vector basic, direction

Tags: vectors

I have basic vector exercise and I have problem understanding vector directions.

Parallelogram $ABCD$, $AB = u$ and $AD = v$.
Dot $E$ split $BC\ 1:3$ and Dot $F$ split $AD\ 1:1$

present $EF$ with $u$ and $v$

[image]

Right answer should be: $EF = -u - \frac14v$

I calculated it like this:

$$\begin{align}
EF &=\ ?\\
EF &= EB + BA + AF\\
EB &= \frac34 CB \implies \frac34 CB = \frac34 (BA+AD+DC) \implies \frac34(-u+v+u) \implies \frac34 v\\
BA &= - u\\
AF &= \frac12 AD \implies \frac12 v
\end{align}$$

So my answer is: $$\frac54 v - u$$

Can someone tell me what or where I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me what or where I'm doing it wrong?

$$\frac 34{CB}=\frac 34(BA+AD+DC)$$
is wrong because the right hand side equals $\frac 34BC$.

You should have
$$\frac 34{CB}=\color{red}{-}\frac 34(BA+AD+DC)$$